Phusion passenger Rails server error: No such file or directory -- Passenger AppPreloader: /home/deployer/hino/current (LoadError)
I'm deploying a Rails app to a VPS using ruby 3.3.3, Capistrano, NGINX, and Phusion Passenger, and this is the error I got:
App 686138 output: /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/3.3.3/bin/ruby:
App 686138 output: No such file or directory -- Passenger AppPreloader: /home/deployer/hino/current (LoadError)
App 686138 output:
[ E 2024-08-25 15:43:49.5509 686090/Tk age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deployer/hino/current: The application process exited prematurely.
  Error ID: 86cd6d2c
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-k6FIQI.html

It looks like Passenger is unable to find the Passenger AppPreloader due to a No such file or directory error. The path /home/deployer/hino/current exists, so I'm not sure what could be causing this.

Check your permissions

here is my project path deployer@vmi1909179:~/myapp$ the owner deployer has read, write and execute permissions

Check your permissions is useless advice. Check that they are what?

I spent a week trying to solve a similar problem. Turned out to be the bundler gem. The system bundler on my server was a different version than the bundler version on my development machine. Check your Gemfile.lock file. If last line says BUNDLED WITH a different version as "bundle -v" from the command-line, you should work to get them on the same version.
BTW, I found the answer in this long ticket:
https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker/issues/409

The fix is then install bundler on the server with correct version
gem install bundler -v BUNDLED_WITH_VERSION
